# Rules around the daily reputation limit

Tags: support

Having recently experienced (for the first time I remember) the daily reputation limit, I wanted to clarify one of the rules.

When the daily reputation limit is in force, is is just that further votes on questions don't count to personal reputation or is it impossible to up vote on the question?

I don't have a problem with the rules, I just want to understand what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations!

Hitting the rep-cap makes up-votes contribute nothing to your reputation until midnight UTC. Some other forms of reputation increases are still awarded (eg. accepts, bounties) and this is also true for badges related to upvotes (e.g. good answer, great answer...).

Comment: So the question scores still record the correct voting numbers?

Comment: @matt_black, yes, all votes are recorded and the number shown is upvotes-downvotes

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the first option.  I recently ran into a similar case where I posted [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37941/can-drinking-harmonized-water-prevent-sunburn/37945#37945) that cleared 200 up-votes, but my reputation only went up approximately 1200-1300 points.